# N-level ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I'm trying to implement a N-level ExpandableListView and I'm using these codes for `getChildView` and `getGroupView` :

```
    @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ExpandNode child = (ExpandNode) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    ExpandNode group = (ExpandNode) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (group.hasChild()) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.index_expandable_list, null);
        }
        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myExpandableListView);
        ExpandAdapter adapter = new ExpandAdapter(context, group.getChilds());
        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.index_child_row, null);
        }
        TextView childTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
        childTextView.setText(child.getTitle().toString());
    }
    return view;
}
```

and :

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    ExpandNode group = (ExpandNode) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.index_parent_row, null);
    }
    TextView childTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parentTextView);
    childTextView.setText(group.getTitle().toString());
    return view;
}
```

The problem is when I'm using nested adapters like what you see in `getChildView` , the `groupPosition` value is always 0 in `getGroupView` in the inner adapter and always referring to the first value in the arrayList.
for example:
the values in the arrayList are:

```
Level1
    level1_1
    level1_2
    level1_3
level2
```

but it shows:

```
Level1
    level1_1
    level1_1
    level1_1
level2
```

It happens only when I'm using nested adapters and it works when using `getChildView` like this:

```
    @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ExpandNode child = (ExpandNode) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.index_child_row, null);
    }
    TextView childTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
    childTextView.setText(child.getTitle().toString());
    return view;
}
```

But it's not a N-level list anymore...
Is there ay suggestion how can I fix this?

Other implemented methods in my Adapter mentioned below :

```
    @Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).getChilds().get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).getChilds().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately...

Comment: So you didn't write N-Level ExpandableListView like TreeView at all ?

Comment: I wrote the above code with the above problem :D

Comment: any solution?? I am stuck today in this problem. Or any alternative

Answer (score 0):

When I faced problem. It is in `getChildCount(int)` which is including count of all the child of another `ExpandableListView`. I am still working on it. Will post an answer soon. Will mark star for this question so won't forget to answer